# Compare ASCII Values in C#

Tags: c#, ascii

I'm trying to compare the ascii value of each character in the input and then I want to shift it with a certain distance and reconvert it to valid character. (using Caesar Ciphering Algorithm)

```
 public void Caesar_Cipher_Optimal(string input, int shift)
 {
    res = "";
    int indx;

    byte[] asciiInput = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);

     foreach (byte element in asciiInput)
     {
         //compare if the current char is between[A-Z]
         if(asciiInput[element] >= 65 && asciiInput[element] <= 90)
         {
            //convert the current value of element to int and add the shift value then mod 90
             indx=((Convert.ToInt32(asciiInput[element])) + shift) % 90;
             res += Convert.ToChar(indx).ToString();

         }
     }
 }
```

When I'm testing the code, it's giving me an OutOfRange exception, is it the right way to compare the current ASCII value with what I want?

Comment: You're completely misunderstanding `foreach` loops.

Comment: mmm Can you help me with it then?

Comment: What do you think `asciiInput[element]` does?

Comment: element should be the current value of the for each. 
for example, if I enter 'A' ... it would be 65, so this element should be 65 too right?

Comment: Yes; that's what `element` is.  What do you think `asciiInput[element]` is?

Comment: Shoot, I totally missed that .... Yea I got your point ... 
It should be, 
    if(element >= 65 && element <=90)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, I fixed some errors in your code so it works now!

```
public void CaesarCipherOptimal(string input, int shift)
{
    var res = "";
    byte[] asciiInput = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);

    // Loop for every character in the string, set the value to the element variable
    foreach (byte element in asciiInput)
    {
        if (element >= 65 && element <= 90)
        {
            var indx = (element + shift - 65) % 26 + 65;
            res += (char)indx;
        }
    }

    return res;
}
```

Here's how you can use it: (probably in your `static void Main()`)

```
CaesarCipherOptimal("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", 10);
```

Comment: I almost downvoted you. `char` in C# is not ASCII, it's UNICODE. Depending on where the input string comes from, `input[i]` could very well be a char with a value > 255. If his algorithm needs ASCII, then he needs to decode it like he's doing.

Comment: I'm tired and that was my bad, very embarrassing. :( Fixed now.

Comment: I'm trying to do the opposite process "To Decipher" but it's not working as it should ... any advice?

    public void Caesar_Decipher_Optimal(string input, int shift)
         {

            res = "";
            int indx;
                
            byte[] asciiInput = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);

             foreach (byte element in asciiInput)
             {
                 if (element >= 65 && element <= 90)
                 {
                     indx = (90 - element - shift) % 26 + 65;
                     res += Convert.ToChar(indx).ToString();

                 }
             }

Comment: Don't change the function, call it with a negative shift value `CaesarCipherOptimal("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", -10);`

Answer (score 3):

It's your array access using the value from the `foreach` that gives the out of range exception, just as SLaks showed.

You don't need to convert the characters to bytes, as you are only dealing with characters that are in the range A to Z. Characters are 16 bit values, and convert easily into their character codes as integers.

You would use modulo 26 rather than modulo 90, otherwise you would end up with characters with character codes from 0 to 64. You can calculate 26 as the difference between `'A'` and `'Z'` to avoid the magic number.

Doing calculations on the character code directly means that you have to do a check afterwards to clean up out of range values. Instead convert the 65-90 range to 0-25, do the calculation, and convert back. Subtract 65 (`'A'`) from the character code, add the shift, apply the modulo, and add 65 back.

```
public static string Caesar_Cipher_Optimal(string input, int shift) {
  return new String(
    input.Where(c => c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
      .Select(c => (char)((c - 'A' + shift) % ('Z' - 'A' + 1) + 'A'))
      .ToArray()
  );
}
```

Comment: Introducing LINQ that I already have trouble reading to a new programmer. Really? +1 for the explanation tho!

Comment: Thanks for the piece of code with the explanation
I want to take into consideration the upper and lower cases and the space character